# Normalize Tensor Image - Optimization

Tags: python, pytorch

Im using a torchmodel to do the inference on. While running the inference I noticed that the normalization of the tensor image consumes half the inference time.

The function that is called:

```
input_image_normalizer = Compose([
    ToTensor(),
    Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
])
```

When removing the normalize function, the inference FPS is doubled.

Is there any optimization that can be done to lower the time of the normalization operation? I'm thinking of putting the Normalize function on the GPU instead? If so how could that be done? 
I have CUDA, and torchvision.

Normalize function: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.Normalize

Comment: Do you perform inference on single image or on batch?

Comment: I suspect that this transform is done on CPU, as Normalize operates on a tensor this could be done on GPU instead. Try to remove this function and replace it with a `to_tensor().cuda()` and then apply the normalisation with tensor operations.